# Create Dictionary item on the fly with operator[]

Tags: c#, dictionary, operators

Normally when you create a `Dictionary<Tkey, TValue>` you have to first go and add k/v pairs by calling add on the dictionary itself.

I have a `Dictionary<string, mycontainer>` where `mycontainer` is a container of other objects.  I need to be able to add things to the mycontainer quickly so I thought maybe I can overload the subscript `operator[]` to create a `mycontainer` on the fly if it doesn't already exist and then allowing me to call add on it directly, as such:

`mydictionnary["SomeName"].Add(myobject);`  without explicitly having to go create mycontainer every time a container with the said name doesn't exist in the dictionary.

I wondered if this is a good idea or should I explicitly create new mycontainer objects?

Comment: You should create your own class that does this.

Comment: Mind giving me an example on how to overload the operator?  Should I derive from `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make your own class that wraps a `Dictionary<TKey, List<TItem>>`.

The indexer would look like this:

```
public List<TItem> this[TKey key] {
    get {
        List<TItem> retVal;
        if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out retVal))
            dict.Add(key, (retVal = new List<TItem>(itemComparer)));
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might as well do `myCustomClass.Add( key, subkey, value );`  so the code can be easily understood and intellisense will guide it's usage.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for explicit code - implicit overloading of an indexer is not really a common situation and will probably bite in a few months time when someone else will be reading your code.